# What I have to do for a page template to be both in staged and online?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

If a page template is staged then we synchronize to make it online but If we want a page template to be both staged and online then what we have to do.

Comment: This is not possible because PageTemplate can have only one CatalogVersion, why do you need the same PageTemplate for both stg and online ?

Comment: I have face the question on a interview so I asked.

Comment: So what will be the answer we can't do both staged and online right ?

Comment: It could be just a tricky question to test your certainty, the answer could be divided into two part. (1) Functional : it has no sense to have one PageTemplate for both stg and online hence why do we need to have two CatalogVersion (staging, Online) in this case then!!, (2) Technical : it's not possible because PageTempate is a synchronizable item, and synchronizable item can have only one single CatalogVersion.

Comment: Got it..Thank you so much ..